# Installed Morrowind, suddenly the data files of Skyrim transform into "Morrowind Plugin"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, pc, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

So a couple of days ago I bought *Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind*. I installed it, played for some time. Then I opened *Skyrim* and suddenly all the textures were messed up (looked detailess and white). I closed the game and checked the Data files, and boom, the texture files, the mods, everything was labeled as Morrowind Plug-ins. I went and uninstalled *Morrowind*, but the Data files were still labeled as Morrowind Plug-ins, and the problem persisted.

Any help guys?

**EDIT:** So I know that you all would think of reinstalling *Skyrim*, which makes sense, but here is the thing. I am on a vacation in my village. It came as a kind of surprise that I coudn't install Wi-fi, so no Steam. (Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, guess I have to return to the city.)

Comment: Reinstall Skyrim and make sure you aren't installing them in the same place

Comment: I would try what @Dallium says. Reinstalling should re-write whatever associations Windows has created, as well as resetting whatever associations Skyrim made to those files. If every little rock texture was given a similar "rock01" name between Morrowind and Skyrim, then perhaps the game just used the "newest" one (that being Morrowind, as in most recently installed).

Comment: "the mods"... that means you're using a mod manager? Uninstall *everything*, clean your registry and reinstall. Or try using the manager's undo/uninstall feature.

Comment: Alternatively, you could uninstall Skyrim and re-install Morrowind.

Comment: I'm pretty sure neither of the games themselves can do this to each other. The culprit is your mod manager, I think, having made a bad registry entry (or possibly an ini setting). Which will persist until you get the manager working right or properly un/re - installed.

Comment: Tittle should read: "I installed [game] *and* some mods, now it's messed up" ;)

Comment: File associations cannot do this: they are simply hints for when you manually open/print/right-click+context menu a specific file so Windows knows which program to start first. You probably ran a poorly programmed Morrowind patcher that scanned your files and edited them (such as some sort of HD texture replacement), or you have a "morrowind fixer" DLL that hooks into DirectX calls (etc).

Comment: Im pretty sure the issue here is that both skyrim mods and morrowind mods use .esp and .esm extensions (Elder Scrolls plugin, Elder Scrolls main iirc). Basically, as long as both games read their own files, I doubt there'd be any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Windows bases file associations on the extension, not on the file content. Morrowind, Oblivion, and Skyrim mods have differences in internal structure, but all have the same extensions, `.esm` (Elder Scrolls Master), `.esp` (Elder Scrolls Plugin), and `.bsa` (Bethesda Softworks Archive). So installing the construction set for one game will overwrite any file associations set up by the other games.

This doesn't affect the games themselves. They don't care about the windows file associations and each one has its own, independent list of files to load. So you can still play Skyrim just fine even if windows thinks that all of its files belong to Morrowind.

It *does* affect what happens if you double-click on the files, so if you want to edit Skyrim mods, you'll need to do it by opening the Skyrim construction set and then loading the files from there, rather than just double-clicking on the plugin file.

To fix this, you'll need to either reinstall the Skyrim construction set, or manually change the file associations for each file -- but this is only a partial fix, because now all the *Morrowind* files will show up as belonging to *Skyrim*. This is an intrinsic limitation of the way windows handles file associations.